# TypeError: channel.join is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello I am a bit stuck here, I am trying to make my bot join VC but it returns:

> (node:847) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: channel.join is not a function

Help would be appreciated :)

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get("757004209701912587");
  if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    // Yay, it worked!
    console.log("Successfully connected.");
  }).catch(e => {
    // Oh no, it errored! Let's log it to console :)
    console.error(e);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's really not a function.
After encountering the same problem and searching to no avail for solution for some time, I've stumbled upon this example code: https://github.com/discordjs/voice/tree/main/examples/radio-bot

It uses completely different principles, but by integrating part of it into my code I've managed to create voice connection successfully.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a valid channel you will first need get a guild from your client.

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("YOUR_GUILD_ID");
```

Then you can change your code to:

```
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("757004209701912587");
```

It should work then.

Comment: "Cannot access 'guild' before initialization"

``client.on("ready", () => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("757004209701912587");
  if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("750063752149205222");
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    console.log("Successfully connected.");
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  });
});``

Comment: You did not declare the guild variable